# Transform an unicode to a float

Tags: python, casting

With Django, i've a variable which contains "48.6834"
it type is unicode.

I'd like to tranform this variable in float. When i do `float(MyVar)` i obtain 48.6.
The problem is it's a latitude and i'd like to keep precision.
I've also tried [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) but it seems impossible because it's not a single character (need a single Unicode character as parameter)

Do you know how can i have my precised varibale ?

My code :

```
print  type(request.POST['lat'])
print request.POST['lat']

lat = float(request.POST['lat'])

print  type(lat)
print lat
```

console result:

```
<type 'unicode'>
48
<type 'float'>
48.0
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `float` does not truncate that number to 48.6.

Comment: so can you explain me why my result is wrong ?

Comment: What's wrong about the result? You put in the string 48, and you got the float 48.

Comment: haaaaaaaa. I need to sleep :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont get `48.6` ... you get a float

```
>>> float(u"48.6834")
48.683399999999999
```

you can represent it how you like with format strings

```
>>> "%0.4f"%float(u"48.6834")  #0 padded float with 4 decimal places 
'48.6834'
```

you may be looking for the Decimal module if you are very worried about [floating point errors](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(u"48.6834")
Decimal('48.6834')
```

Comment: Downvoters are on fire today :P By the way, I think the result from `float` might be architecure dependent, in my box `float(u"48.6834")` returns exactly `48.6834`.

Comment: That was on Windows, on Linux I get your result.

Comment: Technically `float` is very hardware-dependent (*not* OS dependent though, barring an actively malicous OS), but in practice you two most likely have the same internal float representation. The difference is that some Python versions are smarter than others about printing floats: They calculate the shortest float literal that produces the original value, instead if stupidly printing 10+ digits.

Comment: i'm under osX. I've added the code i use

Comment: `float(u"48")` will indeed give you `48.0` as your float which is what you have ...

Comment: yes my fault scuse me